# Кто имеет авторские права на плагин, если он написан усилиями сообщества?

Tags: веб-программирование, авторские-права

Мне помогли написать плагин на jquery. Допустим он уникален. Так вот, я считаю что его можно выложить в репозиторий на филды и тд. А как быть с авторством. Автором являюсь я или сообщество?

Comment: Anna, мне кажется, что данный вопрос надо задавать не программистам, а юристам...  Имея неоконченное юр. образование, скажу, что это зависит от многих факторов...

Comment: Если Вам помогали писать плагин за деньги, то он Ваш, если бесплатно - то общий. Если иное не предусмотрено договором)

Answer (score -4):

Я думаю, вам идеально подойдет [лицензия WTFPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Автор вопроса не сможет применить лицензию к коду, если он не единственный автор кода